# Using Google Drive SDK to grant another Drive App authorization to file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have multiple Google Drive Apps published that have different client ids.  When one Drive App creates a file, I would like to set the permissions on that file to allow the second Drive App access to that file.  My use case is that from the first applications ui, I would like to allow the end user to launch the second application.  Currently, the user needs to leave the first application and go to the drive ui and use the context menu to select open with.

In Google Drive UI, there is a context menu that says "View authorized apps...".  I am basically looking for an API to add an entry to that list.

Thanks.

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.  For security reasons, an app can only be granted authorization to see a file via direct user action: specifically opening the file with that app via open-with or the web or Android file pickers.

Comment: Thanks Cheryl.  It would be a nice new feature.  I do not think it opens a security hole if the API required client id and client secret of the other app.  The other option would be a special format for a link to open a Drive File in specific Drive App which would do the prompt to the user if the App isnt currently authorized.  - Something like https://drive.google.com/file/ID/open/appid

Comment: The latter is probably possible already if its your app.. you specify the open url in the app config, or you can get it from the apps list if its installed: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps#resource

Comment: I tried using the Apps resource and it does provide a template for the URL to open the file in my App, but it doesn't prompt the user in any way to grant the App authorization to the file.  So, my App launches - reads the fileid, tries to call Drive API and fails to get the file.  Ideally, if the app doesnt have authorization to the file, it could show a simple UI that says something along the lines of:  "Allow APPName access to the file FILETitle?".  Clicking OK, would then grant the authorization and then continue to open the file.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have the install scope?  See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/install

Comment: Yes, the app has the drive.install scope.  In my use case, the user does have the both apps installed.  Both apps are registered as valid handlers for the mime type.  the user can open the file with either app using the Drive UI.  Calling the open url does launch the my second drive app.  but the app doesn't get added to the authorized apps list for the file.  since the second drive app only has drive.file scope, it can not read the file until the app gets added to that list.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that part of it in the subsequent conversation here.  If the app doesn't have access to the file, than it needs to obtain access via one of the three methods described in the original post in order to gain access.